Cannot play Super Audio CD on VLC 3.0.20
Dell Optiplex 9020
I7 processor
16 gigs RAM
VLC 3.0.20
I bought a used Super Audio CD and I cannot play it using VLC.
It says "check the log".
I enabled logging, restarted VLC but how do I get to read the log?
There are instructions direct from VLC but they don't work.
Cannot find it in Preferences anywhere.
Where is this log stored? Please provide folder location.

You forgot to mention the OS. For Windows there's this but as a plugin for Foobar2000.
